# Automatically log in to the web site (Intranet) as they are already signed in to their PC with the AD account

Tags: c#, asp.net

What we want the users to automatically log in to the web site (Intranet) as they are already signed in to their PC with the AD account?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [Windows Authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323176).  However, it will work best in browsers that support it (namely, IE).  Otherwise, the user might get prompted for a domain username and password when they browse the site.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/907hb5w9.aspx)

One common approach when dealing with this situation, is adding all AD users to a common group, and grant access to that group in your application

#### Web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For example to only allow AD users that belong to the *yourADRole* group:

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="yourADRole"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Another common approach is to use [ASP.Net impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

When you impersonate, the current logged user will be used instead of the application pool identity, therefore, you would need to grant NTFS permissions to the web site folder to allow read access to the AD group, in this example to: *yourADRole*